# Woocommerce: Need to show shipping price and include it in the total

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've inherited a custom built Woocommerce site and am having to make some upgrades but are getting a little stuck.

I can show the cart total before taxes:

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
```

I can show the taxes to be applied:

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_tax();
```

And the final with the taxes applied:

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal();
```

But I cannot find anyway to show the flat rate shipping I have and also the cart total with the shipping cost applied.

I only have one shipping item which is active, flat rate, with all continents applied to make it global. I'm logged in with an address registered but it doesn't display it.

I have tried multiple options including...

```
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
```

...but still no shipping price or cart total with shipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract shipping cost, I would go like this, using `get_cart_shipping_total`:

```
$shipping_cost = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
```

Have a try.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much.
Please excuse my delay in responding, got stuck with other projects.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help Allen.